# How to parse markdown with alternative syntax into HTML with node?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, markdown

I use markdown-it like so

```
const markdown = require("markdown-it")("default", {
    html: true,
    linkify: true,
    typographer: true
});
const htmlText = markdown.render(textFileContent);
```

and it works fine with until I do

```
#Big title

##Title

#Small title
```

which get wrapped into `<p>` instead of `<h1>` `<h2>` . Note this works with Github. etc

but this works

```
Big title
---------

Title
=======
```

I **cannot** change the markdown. User expect it to be parsed like it does in GitHub and stackoverflow.

Comment: Do with an alternative syntax, you probably need an alternative parser.

Comment: What parser do you recommend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like all implementations that follow the [CommonMark spec](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.27/#atx-headings), markdown-it requires a space between ATX-style header indicators and heading text.

This should work:

```markdown
# Big title

## Title

# Small title
```

I believe that this also makes the source easier to read, which is [one of Markdown's fundamental goals](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/):

> The overriding design goal for Markdown’s formatting syntax is to make it as readable as possible. The idea is that a Markdown-formatted document should be publishable as-is, as plain text, without looking like it’s been marked up with tags or formatting instructions.

However, if you wish to support headers without a space you can use the [`markdown-it-lazy-headers` plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-it-lazy-headers):

> `markdown-it-lazy-headers` is a plugin for [`markdown-it`](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) that relaxes the syntax of [ATX headers](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.22/#atx-header) so that you don't have to follow the opening sequence of `#` characters by a space.

Comment: @WalleCyril, there is a plugin you can use to support ATX headers without a space. See my updated answer.